# Handling oscilloscope bitmap data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, signal-processing

I'm using an oscilloscope from Tektronix; its output is formatted as a $n \times (m + 2)$ matrix, where $n$ is the number of vertical divisions and $m$ the temporal scale.

The first $9\times 2$ elements are a header:

```
sampleData[[1 ;; 9, 1 ;; 5]]
```

> `{{Total Rows,252,0,0,0},{Top Row ,0.05,0,0,0},{Row Increment,-0.0004,0,0,0},{Total Columns,1000,0,0,0},{Left Column ,-2.875*10^-10,0,0,0},{Column Increment,1.25*10^-12,0,0,0},{Trigger Point,230,0,0,0},{Trigger Time,0,0,0,0},{Sample Interval,1.25*10^-12,0,0,0}}`

Where I have removed the columns after the sixth, being all zeroes. That is the reason why I put $m + 2$ as a dimension

The remaining rows and columns constitute a bitmap of the acquired signal (I can't show the actual signal, but it's irrelevant):

```
sampleData[[1;;-1, 3;;-1]] = Array[RandomReal[]&,{252,1000}];

ArrayPlot@sampleData[[1;;-1, 3;;-1]]
```

[image: Sample image]

Now, my goal is to use the header rows to add a frame to the plot with the right values (i.e. showing the actual time scale instead of the column number on the x axis, and the amplitude instead of the row number on the y axis).

So far I've only managed to do it "manually", assigning a name to each component and then adding it by playing with the `ArrayPlot` ticks options:

```
timeScale = sampleData[[9,2]];
maxAmpl = sampleData[[2,2]];
amplScale = sampleData[[3,2]];


xticks=Transpose[{Select[Range[0,Length@interfData[[1]]],IntegerQ[#/100]&],timeScale*Select[Range[0,Length@interfData[[1]]],IntegerQ[#/100]&]*10^9}];
yticks=Transpose[{Select[Range[0,Length@interfData],IntegerQ[#/50]&],maxAmpl+amplScale*Select[Range[0,Length@interfData],IntegerQ[#/50]&]}];

ArrayPlot[Array[RandomReal[]&,{252,1000}],PlotRangePadding->None,Frame->{True,True,False,False},FrameLabel->{"Amplitude  (u.a.)","Time (ns)"},FrameTicks->{yticks,xticks},ImageSize->1000,ColorFunction->Function[{x},If[x>0,ColorData["NeonColors"][x],White]]]
```

Which gives me this:

[image: Formatted sample]

I wonder if there is a neater way to handle it.

### EDIT:

As suggested, I tried using `DataRange` to achieve this result. However, the output plot gets distorted. My steps are as follows:

First, I extract from the headers the $x,y$ boundaries:

```
 xRange = topRow + rowIncr * totalRows;
 yRange = leftCol + colIncr * totalCols;
```

where the six parameters on the right-hand side are the correspondent header values. Then, I add `DataRange` to the plot:

```
ArrayPlot[Array[RandomReal[]&, {252,1000}], PlotRangePadding->None, Frame->{True,True,False,False}, FrameLabel->{"Amplitude  (u.a.)", "Time (ns)"}, DataRange{{topRow, xRange}, {leftCol, yRange}}, ImageSize->1000, ColorFunction->Function[{x}, If[x>0, ColorData["NeonColors"][x] ,White]]]
```

But the result is a huge image which I won't attach here to avoid wasting space. It's like every element of the array, first correctly represented as a square, now becomes a rectangle. What I was expecting was just a rescaling of the two axes, as in `ListPlot`. If I add `AspectRatio->Full`, the image size comes back to normal, but only the $0$ ticks appear, even though they're set to `Automatic`:

[image: DataRange Sample]

Comment: Have you tried using the [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) option of `ArrayPlot`? You should be able to extract `{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}` values from your headers; the appropriate ticks would then be generated automatically.

Comment: @MarcoB `DataRange` actually distorts the whole plot instead of just rescaling the axes. Unless I'm doing something wrong with `DataRange->{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}`.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could include the exact code you used and the distorted result you got in your post.

Comment: @MarcoB done. I haven't uploaded the image because it'd just occupy space. Instead, I tried to describe what happens as well as I could,

Comment: Try adjusting the `AspectRatio`? Perhaps you **should** include the image, since it's really the point of the discussion...

Comment: I just tried. It gives me a `Not enough memory available to rasterize Notebook expression.` error. Playing with `AspectRatio` works but the ticks, if set to `Automatic`, won't be shown, only the zero will appear.

Comment: @MarcoB I added the result with `AspectRatio -> Full`